# How do I add an OR condition in a graphql where statement?

Tags: graphql, where-clause, strapi

I cannot get a WHERE statement working with an 'OR' condition in Strapi via graphql playground.

I would like to return all results where either the 'title' OR 'content' fields contain the search_text.

I have tried the following:

```
articles(where: { 
or: [
  {"title_contains" : "search_text"},
  {"content_contains" : "search_text"}
 ]
}) {
title
content
}
```

but an error is returned.

**ERROR**: "Your filters contain a field 'or' that doesnt appear on your model definition nor it's relations.

Some statements that work (but not what I am after):

```
where: { "title_contains" : "sometext" }
```

working, but behaves as an 'AND'

```
where: { 
"title_contains" : "search_text", 
"content_contains" : "search_text"
}
```

Comment: Hello! This feature is not available in Strapi.
Can you please create a feature request on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 15):

As of July it's possible to do it like this

```
(where: { _or: [{ someField: "1" }, { someField2: "2" }] })
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround here is to create a custom Query and make a custom database query that matches your need.

Here is how to create a custom GraphQL query: 
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/graphql.html#example-2

To access the data model, you will have to use `strapi.models.article` (For an Article model) and inside this variable, you will access to native Mongoose or Bookshelf function. So you will be able to query with an OR